# Show Matlab legend text in datatip

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

In some situations it would be convenient to have the datatip for a datapoint display the corresponding legend entry, in addition to the x- and y-values.

How can I make Matlab show the corresponding legend text in the datatip of a plotted datapoint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can customize the data shown in the datatip by providing a custom `UpdateFcn` programatically.

**Example:**

```
fh = figure;
plot(rand(10,2));
legend('foo', 'bar');

datacursormode on;
dcm = datacursormode(fh);
set(dcm,'UpdateFcn',@customdatatip)
```

**customdatatip.m**

```
function output_txt = customdatatip(obj,event_obj,str)
pos = get(event_obj, 'Position');
output_txt = {...
    ['X: ', num2str(pos(1),4)]...
    ['Y: ', num2str(pos(2),4)] ...
    ['legend: ', event_obj.Target.DisplayName]...
};
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: The DisplayName property is a empty string until the legend is created. Once set it remains even if the legend is hidden, which is nice in some situations.

Comment: Is there any matlab documentation that details this behaviour? I have been googling to find what else is available in event_obj.Target but can't find anything on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to set a custom function to create the datatip text. The easy way is right-clicking in the plot and choosing  'Select-' or 'Edit Text Update Function'.

The function receives an event-object, whose 'Target' property is the handle of the clicked data. When using legends the text is stored in the 'DisplayName' property of that data.

Here is an implementation:

```
function output_txt = legendtip( obj,event_obj)
% Display the position of the data cursor
% obj          Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Handle to event object
% output_txt   Data cursor text string (string or cell array of strings).


try
    p = get(event_obj,'Target');
    legendtext = get((get(event_obj,'Target')),'DisplayName');
catch err
    disp(err.message)
end

pos = get(event_obj,'Position');

if ~isempty(title)
    output_txt = {legendtext ,...
        ['X: ' num2str(pos(1),4)],...
        ['Y: ' num2str(pos(2),4)]};
else
    output_txt = {['X: ' num2str(pos(1),4)],...
        ['Y: ' num2str(pos(2),4)]};
end
```

Tested on 2014b.